# Finding intergers $>2$ satisfying $^{−2}=k^{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Question:

*Find all integers $>2$ such that the number $^{−2}$
is the $n$-th power of an integer.*

I have solved this question on my own and I need a solution verification. If my attempt is incorrect or missing something crucial, could you please provide me a suggestion of how to improve this?

Comment: For a question tagged "solution-verification", I believe it's best to include your solution in the question itself. Others then can provide their comments and suggestions as their own answers.

Answer (score 1):

We can observe that $=4$ works, as $4^{4−2}=2^{4}$, and prove that no other integer $n>2$ does (though both $n=1$ and $n=2$ do).

Let $n=p^{e_{1}}_{1}⋯p^{e_{k}}_{k}$ be the prime power decomposition of $n$.Then $n^{n−2}=p^{(n−2)e_{1}}_{1}⋯^{(n−2)e_{k}}_{k}$, and this is an n-th power if and only if $n|(n−2)e_{i}$ for all  $1≤i≤k$. If $n$ is odd then $gcd(n,n−2)=1$ so this requires that $n|e_{i}$ for each $i$. But any prime $p$ raised to the n-th power already exceeds $n$, since $2^{n}>n$ for all $n$. So for $n^{n−2}$ to be an n-th power $n$ must be even, say $n=2m$. Then $gcd(n,n−2)=2$, and so $2m|(2m−2)e_{i}=2(m−1)e_{i}$, and hence $m|(m−1)e_{i}$, for all $i$. Since $gcd(m,m−1)=1$ this means that $m|e_{i}$ for all $i$. Now no odd prime $p$ may occur in the decomposition of $n$, because $p^{m}>2m=n$ already for any $p≥3$ and $m≥1$. Thus we must have $n=2^{e}$, so $m=2^{e-1}$. And finally, we can’t have $e≥3$, because for such $e$ we have $2^{e−1}>e$, so $m=2^{e−1}$ can’t divide $e$ as would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is spot on, and distinguishing cases for odd and even $n$ seems necessary. However, you are missing a conclusion. It seems that you have excluded all integers $n>2$ except $n=4$. So it remains to check $n=4$, and it is good form to make your conclusion explicit at the end.

I might note that it is not necessary to involve a prime factorization of $n$. From $n^{n-2}=x^n$ it follows, if $n$ is odd, that $n=y^n$ for some integer $n$. Then $y>1$ as $n>2$ but then $y^n>n$, a contradiction.

Similarly, if $n$ is even, say $n=2m$, then it follows that $(2m)^{m-1}=x^m$ and hence again that $2m=y^m$ for some integer $m$. Then $y$ is even and $2m=2^my^m$ from which it easily follows that $m\leq2$. Of course $n>2$ implies $m>1$ and so $m=1$ yields the unique solution $(n,x)=(4,2)$.