# Find all integers $n, n\gt2$ such that $n^{n-2}=x^n$ for some $x$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponentiation

We can express this alternatively as $n^{n}=n^{2}x^{n}$. So the number raised to the power of itself has to be proportional to some number to the $n$-th power, but cannot be equal, naturally. I am not sure how to tackle the $n^{n}$ expression.

How would one attempt this problem or perhaps similar problems like this involving $n^{n}$ terms?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I assume $x$ also has to be a (positive) integer?

Comment: (Assuming $x$ is to be an integer) One solution is $4^2 = 2^4$. Try looking at it this way : imagine some prime $p$ divides $n$, and say $\alpha$ is the largest power of $p$ dividing $n$. What is likely to be the largest power of $p$ dividing $x$? Alternately : $x =n^{\frac{n-2}{n}}$. The right hand side is irrational using a typical contradiction argument with primes, unless $n$ is a $\gcd(n-2,n)$th perfect power.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4313210/finding-intergers-2-satisfying-%e2%88%922-kn/4313706#4313706

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ and $x$ be integers such that $n>2$ and $n^{n-2}=x^n$. Then $n^{n-2}$ is an $n$-th power.

If $n$ is odd then $n$ and $n-2$ are coprime, so $n^{n-2}$ is an $n$-th power if and only if $n$ is an $n$-th power. Of course $n$ is an $n$-th power if and only if $n=\pm1$. This yields two solutions $(n,x)=(1,1)$ and $(n,x)=(-1,-1)$.

If $n$ is even then $n$ and $n-2$ are both even, say $n=2m$ and $n-2=2(m-1)$. Then the equation $n^{n-2}=x^n$ is equivalent to $(2m)^{m-1}=x^m$. As before this implies that $(2m)^{m-1}$ is an $m$-th power, where $m$ and $m-1$ are again coprime. So $(2m)^{m-1}$ is an $m$-th power if and only if $2m$ is an $m$-th power. This happens only if $m=1,2$, yielding the solutions $(n,x)=(2,1)$ and $(n,x)=(4,2)$.

Comment: @markvs You could assume $x$ to be rational and reach the same conclusion, with only marginally more effort, if you like.

Comment: @markvs Well if you allow $x$ to be algebraic the question is completely trivial.

Comment: @markvs Okay.${}$